# sql select in table grammage

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
| id | type_id    | grammage| price     | 
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 1          |      20 |        44 |
|  2 | 1          |      50 |        80 | 
|  3 | 1          |     100 |       110 | 
|  4 | 1          |     250 |       180 | 
|  5 | 1          |     500 |       250 | 
+----+------------+---------+-----------+
```

I want to select price per grammage 
Exemple : select 150 gram

Comment: But there isn't 150 gram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using laravel database builder:

```
$weight = DB::table('weight')->where('grammage', '150')->first();

echo $weight->price;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(...);

$arrayValues = array();

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `price`, `grammage` FROM `exampleTable`");

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
       echo 'Grams: '.$row[1].'g  Price: '.$row[0];
       echo ' Price per gram: '.round($row[0]/$row[1],2).'<br/>';
    }
}
```